# how to write subscriber and publisher for webcam?

Tags: ros, gscam, webcam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, I am new to ROS and its features. I want to know the code for subscriber and publisher for taking picture from my integrated laptop webcam and store in the hard drive. I am familiar with gscam feature to take pictures from my webcam.
But i want to use it as subscriber and publisher.
please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211894/how-to-write-subscriber-and-publisher-for-webcam?/) by [Prashant Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22864/prashant-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See there
http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam

is an v4l driver

install the packet

- sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-usb-cam
- source PATH_TO_YOUR_WS/devel/setub.bash
- rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node ~video_device "/dev/video0"

and you have a video publisher

and some more code
https://rosstitchernode.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/ros-and-opencv-with-usb_cam/

Install  UVC

- sudo apt-get install  install ros-indigo-libuvc  ros-indigo-libuvc-camera
- sudo echo '# UVC cameras
  SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="b2eb", MODE="0666"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/99-uvc.rules

  where the ID (idvendor and idProduct from you wabcam)
- sudo rmmod snd-usb-audio
- sudo rmmod uvcvide
- sudo udevadm trigger

Test

- source PATH_TO_YOUR_WS/devel/setub.bash
- roscore &
- rosrun libuvc_camera camera_node &
- rosrun image_view image_view  image:=/image_raw

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Prashant Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22864/prashant-kumar/) on 2015-06-23**:
doesn't help..
can you give me a sample code for it?

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2015-06-23**:
http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Use_a_Webcam_in_ROS_with_the_usb_cam_Package

there is some exampel code for the usage ov usb_cam

**Comment by [Prashant Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22864/prashant-kumar/) on 2015-06-24**:
if you are talking about image transport then I know it..and I can use gscam for taing snaps but not as subscriber and publisher.
Rather, I want to take snaps from my webcam by subscriber and publisher. which is getting me in trouble.

**Comment by [Prashant Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22864/prashant-kumar/) on 2015-06-26**:
in the link that you gave in the above comment,
"rosmake --rosdep-install"  is not working.
secondly, it's not the code for subscriber and publisher, it's just a launch file code.

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2015-06-26**:
Say exactly what you like to have. A Program wicht publish picture. Write your self a Program witch read the camera and publish the picture.

subscriber:
you like only to see the pricture
you like to work with the picture

you like to trigger a photo with you subscriber and then compute the picture

**Comment by [Prashant Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22864/prashant-kumar/) on 2015-06-27**:
thanks for updated answer..but I am getting error as follows when I run the launch file:-
"[ERROR] [1435430293.861984376]: Webcam: expected picture but didn't get it..."
I can see my camera gets activated but no image is shown in the pop up window..its just full black..
any suggestions?

**Comment by [Prashant Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/22864/prashant-kumar/) on 2015-06-27**:
Oh I got it. I just had to change the pixel format.
thanks for the help.
can you please tell me how to do the same using uvc_cam/libuvc_cam. In this case also my camera gets activated but no image is there in the window.